# what's the word for the photo gallery/slide show for individual product

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

Question as above, you can click on the link to see what I actually look for
[sephora product example](https://www.sephora.com/product/moroccan-spice-eyeshadow-palette-P68998645?icid2=just%20arrived:p68998645:product)

What do you guys call the product pictures and slides section?
Is there any library that I can use? something like bootstrap or semantic UI.

Thank you!

Comment: That site seems to be using the [HammerSlider](https://github.com/davidcetinkaya/hammer-slider) "infinite carousel" plugin.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a clear example of what you are asking on that site. But You might be looking for a [carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/). Basically it's a slideshow, you just have to decide the size so it fits well. Or as a tooltip/popup.

Good luck